# Atheros wifi configuration on ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers

I can't get my hp laptop that come with vista on linux cause my wifi don't work ...

I know for ndiswrapper but the opensource drivers are betters (madwifi,ath5k,ath9k).

My card work with madwifi or ath5k cause it's a g card ... (7000 something I think)

The big problem is to get the good driver and configure network-manager properly ...

Thanks for your help !!!

P.S. Ubuntu doc isn't clear, the irc channel help is hopeless (ubuntu is a noob distro so ...), ubuntu forums aren't better and I'm mostly an Archlinux user now maybe that doesn't help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic subversion
svn checkout http://svn.madwifi-project.org/madwifi/trunk/ madwifi-ng
cd madwifi-ng
make
sudo make install
modprobe -v ath_pci
```

That should do it. If not, post your error messages.

Comment: Seem not working, it worked a little but never connected and the card seem not installed anymore ... It now worked another after a try of modprobe -v ath_pci, I have to load that module at start right ???

Comment: Do I add ath_pci to /etc/modules ???

Comment: yes you have to add it to /etc/modules